# Positioning text over canvas: relative/absolute positioning? z-index?

Tags: html, css, position

I have two donut graphs using Chart.js and two div elements. I'm trying to position the divs on top of the charts, but am having no luck. Of note is that the charts are side-by-side.

```
<div id="breakdownWrap">hi</div>
<div id="scoreWrap">hello</div>
<canvas id="reviewBreakdown" width="150" height="150"></canvas> &nbsp;
<canvas id="reviewScore" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
```

My understanding is I need the div as a parent element, but doing so loses my formatting (charts can no longer be side by side). I'm trying to get the text dead-center within each graph.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/of5a8ub5/

Comment: Please make a JSFiddle

Comment: @AhmadSharif I'm posted a fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I work with your JSFiddle, changing the structure (HTML), adding some CSS, and I get the result that you want.

HTML:

```
<div id="breakdownWrap" class="wrapper"><div class="text">hi</div>
<canvas id="reviewScore" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
</div>
                            <div id="scoreWrap" class="wrapper"><div class="text">hello</div>
<canvas id="reviewBreakdown" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.text{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 150px;
}

canvas{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Take a look and tell me if this solve your problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/of5a8ub5/3/

Comment: Wonderful, however the hover text is now lost on the right chart.